# Jest cannot resolve any types or interfaces from global namespace, but does for functions

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, typescript-typings

I initialized a brand new NestJS project and immediately attempted to use the jest.Mocked generic found in the namespace but typescript complains that it does not exist. From the looks of it, everything except the jest functions are being found.
[image]

I then attempted to remove NestJS's Jest configuration in package.json and follow the examples from ts-jest but the types are still not resolving. Could I have missed a step? I've repeated this process about 4 times across two different machines; twice with NPM and twice with PNPM. I must be missing something as no one else seems to be having this issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Initialize a new NestJS project: `nest new test`
2. Modify the app.controller.spec.ts that comes with the project to use any type in the jest namespace:

```
  let appController: AppController;

+   let test = jest.Mocked<AppController>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
```

3. Run jest: `npm run test`

I can set up a repo if necessary but I'm really not doing much outside the few steps NestJS or ts-jest suggests...

Thanks!